# Find the probability that a family has $k$ kids and two of them are boys (no more boys)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

I came across this problem in an exercise book.

The actual question contains two parts. Let $P(k)$ denotes the probability that a family has $k$ kids. Given $P(0)=P(1)=a$ and

$P(k)=(1-2a)\cdot 2^{-k+1}$, $k\geq 2$

And the probability of having boys and girls are the same (i.e. $Q(B)=Q(G)=\frac{1}{2}$) $Q$ just the notation denotes the probability of having boys and girls.

Suppose a family has already has two boys (and just two boys),

1. Find the probability that the family only have 2 kids.
2. Find the probability that the family have another two girls (and just two girls)

> I am guessing to use beysian theorem for the first question that
> $P(k=2|BB) = \frac{P(BB|k=2)P(k=2)}{P(BB)}$ .
> And for the numerator is
> $P(BB|k=2)P(k=2) = \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2}\cdot(1-2a)\cdot\frac{1}{2}$
> denominator is
> $P(BB) = \sum^\inf_{k=2}\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2}^{k-2}\cdot P^k_2\cdot(1-2a)\cdot 2^{-k+1}$, $P^k_2$ is the permutation with coefficient k and 2 i.e. $\frac{k!}{2!(k-2)!}$

How can one simplify the expression on the denominator?

Comment: I wonder that probability of a family with $k$ children is not $0$ for sufficiently large $k$.

Comment: I think i will. suppose a = 0.4, and k = 20, it will result in a probability of 1.9e-7. so it did converges to zero for large k

Comment: It converges I agree, but other than in reality it is never zero. :)

Comment: hhh. i see. the problem could add an extra bit on this. But let just stick with this :)

Comment: Ok. :) What is your question? It seems that so far everything's correct in your calculations.

Comment: oops, I should make it explicitly. So if I am on the right track. can one simplify the sum in the denominator? I am stuck with the permutation term.

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understood your question you'd like to compute:
$$
(1-2a)\sum_{k=2}^\infty \binom k2 2^{-2k+1}=2(1-2a)\sum_{k=2}^\infty \binom k2\left(\frac14\right)^k
$$

For this you could use the easy to remember expression:
$$
S_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom knx^k=\frac{x^n}{(1-x)^{n+1}}.\tag1
$$

To prove the expression observe that:
$$
S_{n}(x)=\frac{x^n}{n!}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k=\frac{x^n}{n!}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\left(\frac1{1-x}\right)=\frac{x^n}{n!}\frac{n!}{(1-x)^{n+1}}.
$$

Comment: what happen if k is smaller than n for the permutation?

Comment: The binomial is $0$ in this case.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much!